# Google opens new windows

Tags: google

In Google, whenever you click those links on top of each Google page (Ex Mail, Calendar, Docs, etc. the shortcuts) it opens everything in a new tab/window.

Is there any way to make Google open them in the same window?

Answer (score 1):

So, in Google Docs, there's a setting to make docs open in the same window/tab.

However, the other Google pages, you can't really prevent them from opening new tabs/windows. One trick, however, is instead of clicking the link to the page you want, drag the link to the address bar of your browser. It's not very elegant, but it keeps the page you're requesting in the same tab/window.

Also, if you're Firefox savvy, you can change one of the [config settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow) to force pages that want to open new tabs/windows to open the link in the current tab/window. You need to change the value for `browser.link.open_newwindow` to '1' in `about:config`.

Comment: That would work, but the problem is that that will apply to all pages, I just want this to apply to those top elements.  I wrote a firefox plugin to do this:

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/242695/

Comment: The google bar no longer opens these links in a new window.

Comment: @Dez, but I believe they still open in a new tab, which is also one of the issues the op stated.

Comment: @kchau I should have said window/tab in my original comment. My current google toolbar doesn't open a new tab or window. I have duplicated this in Chrome Latest (signed in & not signed in) as well as Firefox latest (signed in and not signed in)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're talking about the search settings in google.
Under search settings: "Open search results in a new browser window"
I prefer this setting for long lists.